# Service registration

Tags: dependency-injection, simple-injector

During `App_Start` I am having issues with requesting the instance of a service. The error below states that the service is not registered. In the example below it is the "AService" that is blacked out.

Bellow is the exception that is thrown:

[image: Registration Error]

The code below registers all of the services to a container.

```
public override void Bind(ref IContainer container)
{
    base.Bind(ref container);

    container.Register<IAService, AService>(DependencyScope.PerInstance);
    container.Register<IBService, BService>(DependencyScope.PerInstance);
    container.Register<ICService, CService>(DependencyScope.PerInstance);
    container.Register<IDService, DService>(DependencyScope.PerInstance);            
    container.Register<IHelperService, HelperService>(DependencyScope.PerInstance);         
}
```

The code below is a test for manually creating the service and all of its dependencies manually.

```
DbContext context = new DbContext("myConnectionString");
DataManager manager = new DataManager(context);
AService service = new AService(manager, new HelperService());
```

**Stack Trace**

```
   at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.VerifyExpressionBuilding()
   at SimpleInjector.Container.VerifyThatAllExpressionsCanBeBuilt(InstanceProducer[] producersToVerify)
   at SimpleInjector.Container.VerifyThatAllExpressionsCanBeBuilt()
   at SimpleInjector.Container.VerifyInternal(Boolean suppressLifestyleMismatchVerification)
   at SimpleInjector.Container.Verify()
```

Comment: I updated the question adding information explaining that it is the "AService". SimpleInjector was chosen by the team.

Comment: The exception message is self explaining. Otherwise post the full stack trace including inner exceptions. It won't be very helpful to hide to service names, but if you must

Comment: I voted this question to be closed [because](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.". Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As your question is currently stated, it is impossible for anyone to answer the question. You blurred out type names that explain what registrations are missing.

Comment: My expected behavior is that the verify process pass which is reliant on "AService" to register properly. In my first code snippet I show that an attempt is made to register the service with a container.